# how to remove particular lines when reading text file in java

Tags: java

i want to delete that line where it finds "RxTracker" 
 this is my text file

```
INFO http-bio-80-exec-1 root - Received data;863071018134228;12.964624;77.523682;NE;23.22376;3.82;0;2013-01-06^08:41:00;
INFO http-bio-80-exec-1 root - RxTracker; IMEINO is 863071018134228
INFO http-bio-80-exec-2 root - RxTracker Invoked. Reading Parameters 
INFO http-bio-80-exec-2 root - Received data;863071018134228;12.964624;77.523682;NE;37.66936;3.82;0;2013-01-06^08:42:52;
INFO http-bio-80-exec-2 root - RxTracker; IMEINO is 863071018134228
INFO http-bio-80-exec-5 root - RxTracker Invoked. Reading Parameters 
INFO http-bio-80-exec-5 root - Received data;863071018134228;12.964624;77.523682;NE;20.92728;3.82;0;2013-01-06^08:44:51;
INFO http-bio-80-exec-5 root - RxTracker; IMEINO is 863071018134228
INFO http-bio-80-exec-3 root - RxTracker Invoked. Reading Parameters
```

this is my java code

```
public void Insert1()  
    {

        try{



            File f=new File("E:/c.txt");
            FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);    
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

            int lineNum = 0;
            String line = null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
               lineNum++;
               if(br.readLine().equalsIgnoreCase("RxTracker"))
               {
                   System.out.println("ji");
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("ji");
               }
             //if ( lineNum %2  == 0 ) continue;
               //else deal with it
             System.out.println(br.readLine());

            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();   
        }
```

Comment: You can not delete lines form a FileReader. you have to write a new files with lines which should not deleted.

Comment: You want to delete it from the same file as you are reading it?

Comment: You can't do it like this. Read the file and every line that you read write into a new file (unless it has "RxTracker"). When you're done, close both files and rename the new file to override the old file.

Comment: just run `sed "/RxTracker/d" c.txt `

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. The code reads each line of a file and writes it to another file.Every time it checks if that line contains RxTracker If that line doesn't contain the RxTracker then it will write that line to the new file and if it contains that string then it will skip that line,

for eg

```
String lineToRemove = "RxTracker ;

 if(!trimmedLine.contains(lineToRemove)) { // check if t he line does not contains it then write it to another file 
            writer.write(trimmedLine);
            writer.newLine();
        }
```